# React table pageIndex issue on when using 2 table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a container. Container wil lfetch the data from server. Container have 2 tabs. Tab switches between 2 tables:

```js
 <div>
    {pageOption.type === 'Firms' ? (
        <DataTable
            columns={columnsFirm}
            data={firmData}
            search={false}
            name={'firm'}
            total={brokerFirm.data?.total}
            onPageOptionChange={(options) => console.log(options)}

        />
    ) : (
        <DataTable
            columns={columnsUser}
            data={brokerUser.data?.data || []}
            search={false}
            total={brokerUser.data?.total}
            name={'user'}
            onPageOptionChange={(options) => console.log(options)}
        />
    )}
```

This is table Implementation:

```js
function DataTable({
    columns,
    data,
    search,
    total = 1,
    loading,
    name,
    onPageOptionChange
}) {
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        page,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        canNextPage,
        canPreviousPage,
        pageOptions,
        setPageSize,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
        prepareRow
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            initialState: { pageIndex: 0 },
            defaultColumn,
            pageCount: Math.ceil(total / defaultPageState.pageSize),
            manualPagination: true,
            autoResetPage: false
        },
        useFilters,
        useSortBy,
        usePagination
    );
    useEffect(() => {
    if (onPageOptionChange)
        onPageOptionChange({ pageSize, newPageNo: pageIndex });
}, [pageSize, pageIndex, onPageOptionChange]);
}
```

Assume I'm in tab1, at pageIndex 2, if I switch to tab2, then the table in tab2, will have pageIndex of previous table, not start from 0. How can I start pageIndex from  0 for tab2's table.Here is the [CodeSandbox link with the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-thunder-g2nbk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it was happening, but wrapping the table component with the div fixed the issue

```js
<div>
  <DataTable
            columns={columnsFirm}
            data={firmData}
            search={false}
            name={'firm'}
            total={brokerFirm.data?.total}
            onPageOptionChange={(options) => console.log(options)}

        />
</div>
```